# CiviCase My Cases Widget not working on main Civi dashboard

Tags: civicase, dashboard

Wordpress 4.3 CiviCRM 4.6.8

Having trouble with the 'My Cases' Widget, as it appears on the Main Civi dashboard. Setting up the 'My Cases' widget only ever produces the error - 'There are no open cases with activities scheduled in the next two weeks. Use Find Cases to expand your search.'

By Contrast the CiviCase Dashboard works fine, specifically the 'My Cases With Upcoming Activities' area, which lists upcoming case activities relating to the user correctly.

One thing it may be related to, is that all cases that need to be listed are custom Case types, using the standard timeline, and they only have Open case = completed on the timeline, as anything else related such as the scheduled meetings or phone calls etc do not have a set time line..

I am very carefully attempting to schedule activities in the cases well within the two weeks, but the cases do not show in the widget.

Any ideas?

Comment: would be helpful if you could recreate this problem on http://civicrm.org/demo

Comment: Hi Coleman, Okay Just set that up in the Wordpress 46 Demo site. Hopefully I am missing something obvious, but case again didint appear in widget (but it does if using default case types)   Steps I took. 1) Enabled Civicase. 2) Went to administer /civicase /case types. 3) Created New Case type, creating new name but using default settings, including standard timeline. 4.) Went to CiviCase, created new Case 'Test Case' using new case type. Success, and says 'Open Case' and 'Completed'. So wouldn't expect this to show in 'My Cases' Widget as there is no scheduled activity yet.

Comment: 5) went to CiviCRM Dashboard,  went to config and added 'my cases' widget. Loads but nothing there, just default message: 'There are no open cases with activities scheduled in the next two weeks.'  6) went back to CiviCase Dash board, clicked 'manage' on new 'Test case' Clicked 'Add Activity' and selected Meeting, filled out form, selected date for 2 days ahead. Saved Case now lists Meeting as 'scheduled' in two days. CiviCase dashboard now correctly lists Test case under 'My Cases With Upcoming Activities' But refreshing widget in Civi Dashboard has 'my cases' still empty.

Comment: It looks as tho there is simply a caching issue that is causing this, as I checked again my own site a day later and the widget was working. 
I will test this again on the demo - and make sure to hit "refresh dashboard data" on the civi dashboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for last comment - this appears to be a simple caching error. Now working.